# iis 7 application pools not starting after installing ibm client access

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ibm, ibm-midrange

I have a windows 2008 dev/testing server setup for testing web apps. I just installed ibm client access (v6r1m0) and after my reboot my sites now get a 503 service unavailable error.

My application pools will not start and I get the following in the application logs:
The worker process for application pool 'ASP.NET v4.0' encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
' trying to read global module configuration data from file '\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CONFIG\machine.config', line number '0'.  Worker process startup aborted.

I had everything working just fine until the ibm install.

I am very grateful to anyone that can help out this developer swimming in unfamiliar waters.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like installing V6R1M0 .net access will adversely modify the permissions on machine.config. Re-adding network service to the permissions of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework{.net version}\Config\machine.config did the trick.

Comment: [See this IBM support article](http://www-912.ibm.com/n_dir/nas4apar.NSF/b6c9b771e38b5ea2862564c00079d110/84158c400658982b86257611003c6d21). Also, the actual XML can be left corrupt in some cases.